# Динамический запрос внутри функции

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте!
Объясните почему нельзя использовать `EXEC('SELECT...')` внутри функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнение запроса внутри функции **может привести к нарушению основного контракта UDF - не изменять состояния базы данных.** Ничто не мешает написать `DROP` внутри `EXEC'a`, что приведет к нарушению этого контракта.

**SQL спецификация UDF:**

> READS SQL DATA or CONTAINS SQL
> Indicates what type of SQL statements can be executed. Because the SQL
> statement supported is the RETURN statement, the distinction has to do
> with whether or not the expression is a subquery.
>
> READS SQL DATA
> Indicates that SQL statements that do not modify SQL data can be
> executed by the function (SQLSTATE 42985).
>
> CONTAINS SQL
> Indicates that SQL statements that neither read nor modify SQL data can
> be executed by the function (SQLSTATE 42985).

Проблема динамических `statement'ов` в UDF заключается в том, что часто реализация `SQL` не может заранее определить, попадает ли выполняемый запрос в одну из разрешенных групп или нет. Поэтому `exec` **изначально помечен как `side-effecting` operator** и его выполнение из функции запрещается (`Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'EXECUTE STRING' within a function.)`

Более подробно о ситуациях, когда вообще оправдано использование `Used Defined Functions` оправдано, можете посмотреть [**здесь.**](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-view-a-stored-procedure-or-a-user-defined-function.html)

---

Кроме того, выполнение запроса через `exec` - это динамическое выполнение. Таким образом (по сравнению со статическими запросами), накладываются серьезные ограничения на оптимизацию запросов - использование индексирования и т.п.

---

Конкретно при использовании `MSSQL` + `CLR` есть [**способ выполнить процедуру**](http://sqlx.blogspot.com/2009/06/run-dynamic-t-sql-statement-from.html) *(которая, в свою очередь, вызывает `EXEC`)* внутри функции, однако, если в рантайме будет обнаружена попытка модификации состояния базы данных, то это приведет к `Exception'у`.

Comment: Ничто не мешает написать DROP внутри EXEC'a, что приведет к нарушению этого контракта. так в stored procedure я тоже могу такое написать там то разрешается.....

Comment: Там идея в том, что это ограничение раньше можно было обойти, используя особенности **Extended** Stored Procedures и хитро вызывая ее внутри `UDF`. Короче говоря, это не разрешается, т.к нарушает спецификацию SQL и я вообще удалил это из ответа.

Comment: Спасибо!всё почитал: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html"> The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL там раздел (Dynamic SQL in User-Defined Functions)...